# Springboot: ConfigurationProperties is not loading values

Tags: java, spring-boot

`ConfigurationProperties` is giving all fields as `null`.

Spring version `3.1.6`

```java
     @Configuration
     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "end-point" )
     public class ConfigProp {
      private String endpoint1;
      private String endpoint2; 
      public String getEndpoint1() {
        return endpoint1;
    }

    public void setEndpoint1(String endpoint1) {
        this.endpoint1 = endpoint1;
    }

    public String getEndpoint2() {
        return endpoint2;
    }

    public void setEndpoint2(String endpoint2) {
        this.endpoint2 = endpoint2;
    }
    }
```

In debug I can see values are present in `targetsource` but not in actual object.

```
    CGLIB$BOUND = false
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_0 = {CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@11318}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_1 = {CglibAopProxy$StaticUnadvisedInterceptor@11319}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_2 = {CglibAopProxy$SerializableNoOp@11320}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_3 = {CglibAopProxy$StaticDispatcher@11321}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_4 = {CglibAopProxy$AdvisedDispatcher@11322}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_5 = {CglibAopProxy$EqualsInterceptor@11323}
    CGLIB$CALLBACK_6 = {CglibAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor@11324}
    endpoint1=null
    endpoint2=null
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Getter and Setter to make the properties initialized.

Also in `properties` add properties this way:

```
end-point.endpoint1="somevalue"
```

Comment: I have added getter/setter also

Comment: yes values are in same way
    endpoint.endpoint1="url1"
    endpoint.endpoint2="url2"

Comment: It should be end-point.endpoint not endpoint.endpoint.

Comment: @Chandrasekharboya if it solves your problem, dont forget to mark it accepted to help others.